# Verificar eventos que ocorreram em um determinado período de tempo

Tags: java, data

Preciso registrar o seguinte evento no meu programa:

- Os Jogadores que matarem 5 vezes durante o intervalo de 1 minuto vão ganhar um prêmio.

O meu mapeamento das classes é o seguinte:

```
public class Game {
    private String name;
    private HashMap<String,Player> players;
    private Player serialKiller;
    private Integer streak; 
}

public class Player implements Comparable<Player> {
        private String name;
        private List<Murder> murderList = new ArrayList<Murder>();
        private List<Death> deathList = new ArrayList<Death>();
}

public class Murder {
    private Date date;
}
```

Arquivo de log:

---

> 30/07/2013 15:34:22 - New match 11348965 has started
>
> 30/07/2013 15:36:04 - Roman killed Nick using M16
>
> 30/07/2013 15:36:05 - Roman killed mane using M16
>
> 30/07/2013 15:36:06 - Roman killed jose using M16
>
> 30/07/2013 15:36:07 - Roman killed trevis using M16
>
> 30/07/2013 15:36:08 - Roman killed santana using M16
>
> 30/07/2013 15:36:05 - noob1 killed noob2 using M16
>
> 30/07/2013 15:36:06 - noob1 killed noob3 using M16
>
> 30/07/2013 15:36:07 - noob1 killed noob4 using M16
>
> 30/07/2013 15:36:07 - noob10 killed noob1 using M16
>
> 30/07/2013 15:36:07 - noob10 killed noob1 using M16
>
> 30/07/2013 15:36:07 - noob10 killed noob1 using M16
>
> 30/07/2013 15:36:07 - noob10 killed noob1 using M16
>
> 30/07/2013 15:36:07 - noob10 killed noob1 using M16
>
> 30/07/2013 15:36:07 - noob10 killed noob1 using M16
>
> 30/07/2013 15:36:07 - noob10 killed noob1 using M16
>
> 30/07/2013 15:36:07 - noob10 killed noob1 using M16
>
> 30/07/2013 15:36:07 - noob10 killed noob1 using M16
>
> 30/07/2013 15:36:33 -  killed Nick by DROWN
>
> 30/07/2013 15:39:22 - Match 11348965 has ended

O tempo `Date` da morte dos adversários é definida na classe usuário pela lista da classe Murder.

Como posso obter saber se o jogador ganhará o prêmio sem usar Threads ?

Comment: Crie uma Thread que faça a verificação e que conte o tempo do sistema. **Dúvida:** precisa que todas as 4 próximas mortes sejam em menos de 60s da primeira? Ou pode implementar para verificar se houve mais de 5 mortes em um minuto?

Comment: @Kyllopardiun a parada é assim, to fazendo upload de um log de um arquivo que tem as informações da partida... aí a partir dele eu gero as informações....
e sobre "Dúvida: precisa que todas as 4 próximas mortes sejam em menos de 60s da primeira?"
Sim precisam ocorrer em um range de 1 minuto

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui nesse link: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Threads/Simple-Threads.htm

Ele ensina como fazer threads...o que você precisa é fazer uma thread ficar rodando por 60 segundos de forma decrescente e fazendo algo como um "mortes++" e se chegar a 5 você dispara seu evento.

Comment: @Dante eu não estou enxergando a necessidade de usar uma thread, sendo que eu ja tenho tudo, a quantidade de assasinatos que o cara tem e a data que ele matou... o arquivo que eu faço upload ja me informa isso entendeu???? Eu não estou sabendo como usar as informações...

Comment: então coloca o arquivo na tua pergunta e coloca também a parte do código que faz a leitura do mesmo.

Comment: @BlackSheep, se importa de usar `JavaFX` em uma solução?

Comment: Se você já tem todas as informações o que falta? Faz um código que faça a leitura do arquivo (Que deve ser em formato de texto provavelmente) e a cada linha identifica quem é o cara pelo nome e adiciona 1 morte pra ele de acordo com o diferencial de tempo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como não especificou se possui alguma aversão a JavaFX, isto é provavelmente o que procura, já que esta tecnologia permite listas com `Listeners` ou seja é só uma questão de verificar sempre que a lista for modificada se o jogador merece o prêmio.

```
public class Player implements Comparable<Player> {
        private String name;
        private List<Death> deathList = new ArrayList<Death>();
        private ObservableList<Murder> murderList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        public Player(){
            this.murderList.addListener(new ListChangeListener<Murder>(){
                @Override
                public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Murder> c) {
                    if(murderList.size()>5){
                        int lastIndex = murderList.size()-1;
                        Date lastMurder = murderList.get(lastIndex).getDate();
                        boolean flag = true;
                        for(int i=lastIndex-1;i>=lastIndex-5;i--){
                            Date tempDate  = murderList.get(i).getDate();
                            //se em algum caso for maior que 60 descarta o prêmio
                            if(timeDiff(tempDate,lastMurder)>60){
                                flag = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if(flag){
                            //receivePrize();
                        }
                    }   
                }
            });
        }
        public static long timeDiff(Date d1, Date d2){
            return (d2.getTime() - d1.getTime())/1000;
        }
}
```

Comment: Vou ver aqui... acho que consigo ter um rumo com isso aí, eu não conhecia esse JavaFX... pelo que procurei aqui não tem nos repositorios de jar do maven né... mas eu vou me virar aqui... valeu @Kyllopardiun